# x86 Swift calling convention

Tags: swift, assembly, lldb

I have the following Swift 4 code:

```
_ = self.tenArguments(one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4,
                                five: 5, six: 6, seven: 7, eight: 8,
                                nine: 9, ten: 10)
```

This compiles to:

```
0x100003247 <+87>:  mov    edx, 0x1
0x10000324c <+92>:  mov    edi, edx
0x10000324e <+94>:  mov    edx, 0x2
0x100003253 <+99>:  mov    esi, edx
0x100003255 <+101>: mov    edx, 0x3
0x10000325a <+106>: mov    r8d, 0x4
0x100003260 <+112>: mov    ecx, r8d
0x100003263 <+115>: mov    r8d, 0x5
0x100003269 <+121>: mov    r9d, 0x6
0x10000326f <+127>: mov    r10d, 0x7
0x100003275 <+133>: mov    eax, r10d
0x100003278 <+136>: mov    r10d, 0x8
0x10000327e <+142>: mov    r11d, r10d
0x100003281 <+145>: mov    r10d, 0x9
0x100003287 <+151>: mov    ebx, r10d
0x10000328a <+154>: mov    r10d, 0xa
0x100003290 <+160>: mov    r14d, r10d
0x100003293 <+163>: mov    r15, qword ptr [rip + 0x6dd6] ; (void *)0x00000001003a4048: swift_isaMask  0x10000329a <+170>: mov    r12, qword ptr [rbp - 0x48]
```

I know x86_64 calling convention is RDI,RSI,RDX,RCX,R8,R9 but can anybody explain why the code above? Why is 0x1 loaded to edx first then moved to edi? This is then repeated for 0x2 to esi. Why has the compiler not generated:

```
mov edi, 0x1
mov esi, 0x2 ; etc...etc...
```

etc. Is this a speed optimisation by the compiler? Why double the number of ops?

This code was built by Xcode 8.3.2 for iPhone 7 simulator.

Comment: This looks like unoptimised code or missed optimization. I don't know swift and have never looked at its generated output..

Comment: With such question you should not just throw in "this compiles", but explain what build process was used (usually building in CLI terminal and copying command line used with all options is enough for anyone else to try to reproduce your results, and it's simple to put into question. GUI oriented IDEs may be more difficult to describe, but they often have command line behind, and it can be extracted with some kind of verbose build options). Compilers often have many options, affecting resulting machine code a lot.

Comment: This https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/CallingConvention.rst and this https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst#calling-convention might also be of interest.

Comment: This code was built by Xcode 8.3.2 for iPhone 7 simulator.

Comment: Well, the iPhone itself is ARM based, so this is simulation over x86. Without seeing the command line used by Xcode it's hard to tell, how much it sets up optimization for x86 simulation target, maybe they prefer quicker compilation over code performance, as in this case somewhat sub-optimal machine code will perform somewhat closer to the true ARM target result, and quick turn-around time during development is important, but I'm just guessing everything of this (don't have Xcode, nor I do code in swift). The llvm itself *can* produce better x86 machine code, so there's some purpose why this..

Comment: Try  `swiftc -emit-assembly yourMinimalSampleProgram.swift` on the command line, and then add the `-O` option. You'll notice the difference.